# Inverted index for a custom SQL-based web search function

Tags: sql, search, full-text-search

I would like to implement a web search feature but I don't want to use the built-in full-text search function of my rdbms or resort to using elasticsearch et. al.  The reasons are irrelevant.

The dilemma that I'm facing is the need to return results by relevance after a user keys in their search terms.  What I know of is to use

```
ORDER BY score ....
```

but because score is a computed field based on where the corresponding search terms match, no indices is used and thus this solution is practically useless.

Could someone shed some light on whether there are other strategies the industry uses for an sql-based search function? **The objective is to be able to design a schema that enables the use of an index for scoring.**

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh mysql for now